# Getting the rails 'params' without the defaults?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a neat way in rails to get a hash of the params without the default ones of 'action' and 'controller'?  Essentially without any param that wasn't added by me.

I've settled for:

```
parm = params.clone
parm.delete('action')
parm.delete('controller');
```

But wondering if there is a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use except:

```
params.except(:action, :controller)
```

http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Except.html

Comment: Oh, nice! I didn't know that one but I think you would use it in this way: `params.except(:action, :controller)`. It's even more cleaner ;)

Comment: Nice one. I don't suppose this array is defined as a constant anywhere? Then it would be *even* neater, and future proof!

Comment: @Matt Dressel's answer is much safer.

Comment: @aceofspades this answer answers the more generic question of excluding various params. In my case, my `params` can have varying names/number of fields, but I want only and all data from input fields of the form, excluding `utf-8`, `auth_token` etc so this helps with that as far as I can tell

Answer (score 31):

```
request.path_parameters
```

returns path_parameters

```
request.query_parameters
```

returns request_parameters

You are looking for the latter.

Comment: This is the *real* answer!

Comment: would this also exclude things like "utf-8" and "auth_token" ? I'm looking for a way to simply get only and all values from a form's input fields from POST submission

Comment: @mmcrae -- yes it will

Comment: This is misleading. request.query_parameters != request.request_parameters. request_parameters includes url parameters that also show up in query_parameters, however query_parameters does NOT include POSTed variables (ie. form variables) that only show up in request_parameters.

Comment: I agree with @Emeka that this answer should mention the existence of `request.request_parameters` and clarify what `request.query_parameters` returns.

Answer (score 23):

If you are working in a controller, you should also have access to the request object.

To make a long story short, rails and rack groom incoming GET/POST requests (form, xml, json) and pull out the parameters so that developers have a consistent way of accessing them.

ActionDispatch exposes the consolidated list of params via:

```
# ActionPack 3.1.8 - action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb
# Returns both GET and POST \parameters in a single hash.
def parameters
  @env["action_dispatch.request.parameters"] ||= begin
    params = request_parameters.merge(query_parameters)
    params.merge!(path_parameters)
    encode_params(params).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
alias :params :parameters
```

As you can see, params is an alias for the parameters method which is a merged hash of two sub-hashes: **request_parameters** and **path_parameters**.

In your case, you don't want the path_parameters.  Rather than using except, which forces you to know which path parameters you want to exclude, you can access your data via: **request.request_parameters**.

***A word of caution***: You may be better off using :except if you require the hash to be encoded and keys to be accessed as either strings or symbols.  The last line of the parameters method handles that for you:

```
encode_params(params).with_indifferent_access
```

An alternative approach using except and ensuring that you are removing all rails non-request parameters:

```
path_params = request.path_parameters
params.except(*path_params.keys)
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent detailed answer. More future-proof than the :except option, and very useful to know.

Comment: `request.query_parameters` might be what the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: We need definitely more answers like that. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
request.request_parameters
```

it excludes the path_parameters (controller and action)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
request.request_parameters.except(controller_name.singularize)
```

This strips out the nested object that is named after the active controller. For example with the following controller:

```
Class SessionController > ActionController::Base
  def create       
   User.find_by(params[:email]).login(password: params[:password])
   puts request.request_parameters
  end
end
```

With the following posted value from a web form:

```
{email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password123'}
```

The console output will be:

```
{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"password123", "session"=>{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"password123"}}
```

The above lines of code avoid this.