# Using one '_form.html.erb' partial but have different elements appear for certain views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to display certain elements within a partial for a particular view in Rails? For example I'd like the submit button's text to change depending on the view: so if I'm in the new.html.erb I'd like the submit button to appear as, `<%= f.submit 'Create Account' %>` and `<%= f.submit 'Update Account' %>` for edit.html.erb. The unconventional way would be to manually add the custom code into the each view but is there a clever way to do this in my _form.html.erb partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend putting it into the new and edit views. However, you can switch off of `params[:action]` if you want to. As in

```
<%= f.submit(((params[:action] == 'new') ? 'Create' : 'Update') + ' Account') %>
```

Comment: Thanks. What's your reasoning behind putting this line in each view? Doesn't that go against DRY principles? And also how does Rails recognize if I'm using the action parameter if I omit it?

Comment: The action parameter is automatically added to the params hash by the application controller. And I'd put it into each view because it's unnecessary logic in the view in my opinion. Thing is, it's completely an opinion question. If you like it in the _form partial, keep it there!

Answer (score 2):

Use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with i18n for that. SimpleForm make it automatically.

Example:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@message) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I second kdeisz's answer if your intention is to use a single partial. The line he wrote will not be necessary if you use two separate views - You can just use different names on the same button in each view without any need for conditional logic.

To answer your supplemental questions: There is a tradeoff here between future changeability and DRY code. If your new and edit needs will start to differ significantly, you will have a lot of bloated, difficult-to-change conditional logic in your partial if you use it to render major features.

If you keep the views separated, this may repeat a significant amount of code, but it will also make the individual pages easier to change; the functions of each view will be tailored very specifically to the needs of each HTTP verb.

The answer isn't to conform completely to REST or to DRY "just because", but to ask yourself what will result in more work down the road. If your new and edit pages will be basically the same but for a few very minor features, the single partial (DRY) is more practical. If you see them diverging significantly in the future, keep them separated into two views (less DRY but more changeable).

Params. Each request made to Rails will automatically include an action and a controller based on the route the user requests; for example, navigating to `/foo/bar` might trigger action `bar` for controller `foo`, depending on how you've set up `config/routes.rb`. Rails fills in `params[:action]` and `params[:controller]` with these automatically. A good explanation of how this works, and how to access path and request params, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467901/getting-the-rails-params-without-the-defaults).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.